# How to open specific cardview detail activity when notification is clicked

Tags: java, android, firebase

How can i open a specific cardview when the notification is clicked? i am using firebase.

so i have 3 navigation menu which is `Announcements,News,Events`

in each menu there is a list of cardview.

in my notification when you clicked it there is a response of `{deep_link={"page":"announcements","id":"49"}, picture= , url=}` this response is i am passing it to my main activity when the notification is clicked because i think that is where you will process this response to open the cardview that i want.

if the page is announcements i want to open the cardview that has the ID of `49`.

i am new in this kind of problem and i have really no idea on how to start, can anyone help me to figure this out. any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: So you want your recycler view to scroll to an especific position or you want to open a new activity with the card details in it?

Comment: Hard to tell without any code. But I'd say you're correct in receiving the notification in the main activity. I'd probably have some sort of switch statement where I check for the `page`. E.g. if it's an "announcement", create an `Intent` to go to your `Announcements` class (?) and also pass it the id. The `Announcements` class then takes care of showing tha appropriate `CardView` depending on the id. (Note that you'll repeat this behavior in all three classes though, so maybe try to find a single place for it.)

Comment: @DiegoLovera hi sir thank you, what i am thinking based on the response of the notification when clicked is i want to open the cardview for the announcement menu that has the id of ```49```.

Comment: you didn't provided a single line of code, how we can help you? the are dozens of methods, we don't know which will fit into your current code

Comment: @RenielMallari My question remains the same, when you say open the card view, what do you mean? Open it as a dialog?, as a new activity? or make your recycler view scroll to your card view?

Comment: @DiegoLovera i think the only way to do this is to make the recycler view to scroll and find that ID to its list sir.

Comment: hi sir thank you for answering. ill post my code later, ill do first my part and show it to you, its just i have no idea how to start it thats why i didnt post my code because it is still doesnt making sense. sorry sir.